# Read a file in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file

I want to read a text file and store its content as a string through javascript or jquery. I have the full path of the file. How can i do this? Any ideas or suggestions...I need this to work on IE

Regards

IE Version 7,8,9,10

Comment: Where is the file? On the server, or on the client?

Comment: the file is on the client but i am using IE and i am able to get the path using the following:  $("#Submit").click(function () {
            var fil = document.getElementById("file");
            alert(fil.value);

Comment: Which IE versions do you have to support?

Comment: file api needed for local files is not available in older browsers. Suggest you think of different work flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IE8, if ActiveX is enabled, you can create a `Scripting.FileSystemObject` and use it to open and read a local file ([example](http://css.dzone.com/tips/javascript-how-read-and-write)).

In modern browsers, one uses the [HTML5 File API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).